# Python for-loop crashing because string length changes

Tags: python

Having a really silly problem. I'm iterating over a string and removing all non-alphabetical characters. The problem is that when I remove them, the length of the string decreases and my loop crashes because I go out of bounds.

```
for x in s:
    if x.isalpha() == False:
        s = s.replace(x, "")
```

Comment: What do you mean it crashes? You're not using indexing at all so there's no chance of it going out of bound.

Comment: If `s` really is a string, this will not crash, whatever that means. The code you posted will work and produce the intended result both on Python 2 and Python 3. It is however very inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)!

```
s = filter(str.isalpha, s)
```

Comment: This produces a list, not a string

Comment: @mhawke From docs: *If iterable is a **string** or a tuple, the result also has that type; otherwise it is always a list.* Though in Python 3 it returns an iterator so an extra `str.join` call will be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex!

```
import re
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]') #Create a regex that allows on only A-Z and a-z
regex.sub('', s) #This will return the string, stripped of non alphabetical characters
```

Comment: I'd love to, but I'm helping a friend with an assignment and that'd be too advanced for his class. I gotta do it the simple way and my brain is farting.

Comment: Regex's shouldn't be too advanced, but any of the answers posted here will work - there's multiple ways to solve this - pick whatever you choose :)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to loop from end to front if you insist to use loop...

This is the useful trick to handle the length change.

```
for x in s[::-1]:
    if x.isalpha() == False:
        s = s.replace(x, "")
```

Edit: I forgot to mention, to reverse a string, you can do `s[::-1]`

Comment: Just adding that s[::-1] is a shortcut to reverse a string, in case you aren't sure why this solves your problem

Comment: And this is entirely unnecessary as the iterator created using the string at the start of the loop is independent of `s`, it will work even if you delete `s`.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension is the most Pythonic way to do this.

```
s = ''.join([x for x in s if x.isalpha()])
```

The list comprehension builds a list containing alpha characters only, and `join()` returns a string of those characters.